# select a web form and load it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have 4-5 forms which I want to give on my site for the users as an option to use one of them.

I am thinking I'll open a page with screenshots of the forms and if the user clicks on one the form should load using ajax.

I can redirect it to the form but I just want to know is there a way to do it with ajax jquery.

Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>Form Validate and Save</title> <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });   });
     window.onload = initPage;
     function initPage() {
     $.getJSON('formData.json', function(Data) {

      $("#formName").html( Data.load[0].formName ).html();
      $("#fname").html( Data.load[0].fname ).html();
      $("#fmail").html( Data.load[0].fmail ).html();
      $("#fmobile").html( Data.load[0].fmobile ).html();
      $("#fmessage").html( Data.load[0].fmessage ).html();
      $("#mailTo").val( Data.load[0].mailTo );
     });   }
     function sendData() {
    var newformName = document.getElementById('formName').innerHTML;
    var newfname = document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML;
    var newfmail = document.getElementById('fmail').innerHTML;
    var newfmobile = document.getElementById('fmobile').innerHTML;
    var newfmesage = document.getElementById('fmessage').innerHTML;
    var newmailTo = document.getElementById('mailTo').value;

    var newData = {
     formName: newformName, fname: newfname, fmail: newfmail, fmobile: newfmobile, fmessage: newfmesage, mailTo: newmailTo, file:

'formLoad.json', 
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      data: newData,
    }).done(function( formData ) {
      formData = eval('(' + formData + ')');
      $('#formName').html( formData.load[0].formName ).html();
      $('#fname').html( formData.load[0].fname ).html();
      $('#fmail').html( formData.load[0].fmail ).html();
      $('#fmobile').html( formData.load[0].fmobile ).html();
      $('#fmessage').html( formData.load[0].fmessage ).html();
      $('#mailTo').val( formData.load[0].mailTo );
    });   } </script>  </head>   <body>

   <?php
    require_once('login.php');
    ?>
    <?php require_once('formLoad.php'); ?>

 <!-- JavaScript below! -->

<!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->     <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->     <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Validate plugin -->        <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts specific to this page -->      <script src="script.js"></script>

    <!--    <script>            // Activate Google Prettify in this page
                addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);

            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Add prettyprint class to pre elements
                    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');

            });

        </script>-->

  </body> </html>
```

Comment: Yes, you can load a form (just like any other page) via AJAX using jQuery.

Comment: i would have four to five forms like this and each will have diffrent functions in the java script written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather broad question, but I'll try to answer it.

The following approach enables you to put all the forms in one .html file and just give them different ID. (Say `#form1, #form2, #formN`.) If a user selects one, you should just figure out the right ID and then do:

```
$('#elementYouWantTheLoadedFormIn').load('ajax/fileWithTheForms.html #' + formID, function() {
    // Optional callback.
});
```

Comment: `+1`, but for users who have JS turned off, I'd say a better approach is keeping them in separate pages, and use jQuery to prevent the default action and load in the form based on the `<a>`'s `href` attribute.

Comment: for different forms I have different functions in js written can it be done then also.

Comment: @ahren Good point, although it isn't in the question.

Comment: @Gaurav Sure, just execute the code above with a different ID in each function.

Comment: Actually that's not quite correct. Using `load()` in this fashion would strip out any scripts. From the docs: *If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.*

Comment: @ahren It was about loading _forms_ not about scripts!

Comment: *for different forms I have different functions in js* -- Pretty sure he's meaning each form has a different script.

Comment: added the from page in the question above

Comment: @Gaurav I really don't see any forms.

Comment: the form comes from the formLoad.php it just checks the user if it is admin prints a different form.

Thait's it, nothing else..

Comment: Then you don't need any (client-side) scripts. My answer should work. @Gaurav